# Can i dynamicaly create keys for dict in python?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am creating a spider in Scrapy. And I want to scrape table in this way:

- Take every `<tr>`
- Use `<th>` as key and `<td>` as content

**The code I came up with is this.**

```py
def parse(self, response):
        item = {}
        item['code'] = response.xpath('//meta[@itemprop="sku"]/@content').extract_first()
        tables = response.css('.technical-specs')
        for table in tables:
            specs = tables.xpath('tbody/tr')
            for s in specs:
                key = s.xpath('th/text()').extract_first().replace(" ", "_").replace("(", "_").replace(")", "_").replace("/", "").lower()
                value = s.xpath('td/text()').extract_first()
                item[key] = value


        return item
```

But it is not working. Is this posible  to achieve?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what is not working?

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly. And in Python we don't have "associative arrays", we have dicts - probably one of the most used types, so [better to learn how to use them](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dict instance and then add the items inside the loop. E.g:

```py
my_dict = dict() # Can be {} to

for item in items:
  key = item.key
  value = item.value
  my_dict[key] = value

Regards
```

Comment: Yeah I did that. I will add rest of the function in edit. Turns out problem was in extracting data. I used .extract() which makes data unicode, making it unscrapable.

Answer (score 0):

The, now working, code of parse function is updated in my question details. Problem was not in the way loop or dictionary was implemented, but in how I extracted data. I was using **.extract()** which makes response unicode and "unscrapable". **Removing .extract was the fix.**